# c++ populate a std::map create unnecessary objects

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have an Animation that prints in the default constructor, the destructor and in another constructor some distinctive strings:

```
class Animation{
public:
   int x;
   Animation(int x) {
        std::cout << "+ animation\n";
    }

    Animation() {
        std::cout << "+ animation\n";
    }

    ~Animation() {
    std::cout << "- animation\n";
    }
}
```

I want to populate a std::map with this objects, the std::map definition is this:

```
std::map<int, Animation> animations;
```

When I try to populate the map, I do it this way

```
void createAnimations(){
    animations[0] = Animation(10);
    animations[1] = Animation(10);
    animations[2] = Animation(10);
    animations[3] = Animation(10);
    animations[4] = Animation(10);
}
```

When I run the program, prints this

```
+ *animation
+ animation
- animation
+ *animation
+ animation
- animation
+ *animation
+ animation
- animation
+ *animation
+ animation
- animation
+ *animation
+ animation
- animation
```

Why this extra objects are created and destructed?

Comment: You should consult the reference of the function you are using: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: `    animations[0] = Animation(10);` This line, creates an object and calls assignment operator and then destructs the object. What version of c++ are you in? Depending on that there is better way to do.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace).

Comment: I'm using c++17. Is there a way to prevent the default construct?

Comment: @Werem I rolled back the edit that added the post-`emplace` code. If you're encountering a different issue after changing your code, you should post your updated code as a new question, rather than updating this question: your new issue with `emplace` is a different issue than you were originally encountering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the brackets operator of a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` causes the entry to be created (using its Default Constructor) before the assignment is attempted.

It might be better to think about the statement like this:

```
animations[0] //operator[] invoked; default-constructed object created
= //Assignment operator
Animation(10); //Animation object constructed using Animation(int) constructor.
               //Was created as an X-value, will be move-assigned into the default-constructed object
```

If you want to insert into a map without its default constructor being invoked, you need to use `insert` or `emplace`:

```
//May invoke move-constructor, may be elided, depending on how aggressively your compiler optimizes
animations.insert(std::make_pair(0, Animation(10));
animations.insert(std::make_pair(1, Animation(10));
animations.insert(std::make_pair(2, Animation(10));
animations.insert(std::make_pair(3, Animation(10));
animations.insert(std::make_pair(4, Animation(10));

//Will construct in-place, guaranteeing only one creation of the object
//Necessary if the object cannot be move or copy constructed/assigned
animations.emplace(0, 10);
animations.emplace(1, 10);
animations.emplace(2, 10);
animations.emplace(3, 10);
animations.emplace(4, 10);
```

Comment: I used emplace and did the trick to prevent calling the default constructor, but now I'm having a extra destructor call for every call to emplace.